# How do you make a basic fullscreen window in Python?

Tags: python

One that's borderless, doesn't look like a 90's text box, and when you press escape it takes you out of the window completely but doesn't close it.

Comment: It is operating system and GUI toolkit specific. Even on Linux, it would be different with [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/) and [PyGtk](http://www.pygtk.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it to full-screen:

```
import tkinter
example_window = tkinter.Tk()
example_window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```